# Fully faithful functors do not preserve epimorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Give an example of an epi not preserved by a fully faithful functor.

I was thinking about $i:\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ together with the forgetful functor from **Ring** to **Ab**. Only issue is the divisibility of $\mathbb{Q}$ makes it hard come up with the desired pair of arrows.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: The forgetful functor from rings to abelian groups is not fully faithful. For every ring $R$, we have exactly one morphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$, but there are for example certainly more group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That forgetful functor isn't full - I don't think looking at your $i$ will be productive here (maybe I'm wrong!). I'd try thinking about an inclusion of a subcategory into a larger category where the subcategory doesn't contain the target of the morphisms witnessing failure of a certain map to be epi. You could use a simple diagrammatic category like the one [at the top of the wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism)

Comment: Indeed. How about Top$_{T2}$ (space of Hausdorff topological spaces) to Top with the mapping $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Would this work in at least the faithful case?

Comment: @MrHolmes your example of the forgetful functor fom Hausdorff topological spaces to Top works perfectly.